# Django app functions locally, breaks when deployed to DigitalOcean

Tags: python, django, web, jinja2, digital-ocean

This is the error on the DigitalOcean droplet I set up:

## Django Error (line 38 is highlighted)

```
Reverse for 'vendor' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'vendor': u''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'deals/vendor/(?P<vendor>[\\w-]+)$']
...
34                {% if vendors %}
35                  <li class="divider"></li>
36                  <li class="dropdown-header">By Vendor</li>
37                  {% for vendor_item in vendors|slice:"0:3" %}
38                    <li><a href={% url 'deals:vendor' vendor=vendor_item.slug %}>{{ vendor_item.name }}</a></li>
39                  {% endfor %}
40                {% endif %}
```

The error does not occur locally. I see that the keyword is an empty string, so I went to the shell to investigate.

```
>>> from deals.models import Vendor
>>> vendor_qs = Vendor.objects.all()
>>> for item in vendor_qs: print item.slug
...
my-first-vendor
my-second-vendor
>>>
```

Here is the model, view, and url for the page I'm trying to reach:

## models.py

```
...
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## views.py

```
...
def index(request, data=None): 
if data is None:
    data = {}

vendors = Vendor.objects.annotate(Count('deal')) \
    .order_by('name')
data['vendors'] = vendors

categories = Category.objects.annotate(Count('deal')) \
    .exclude(deal__count__lt = 40) \
    .order_by('name')
data['categories'] = categories

return render(request, 'deals/_index.html', data)
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index' ),
    url(r'vendor/(?P<vendor>[\w-]+)$', views.get_deals_by_vendor, name='vendor'),
    url(r'test_type/$', views.view_model_subclass_by_deal), # Remove in production
    url(r'todays_deals/$', views.view_deals_updated_today), # Remove in production
    )
```

Again, 100% of this code works totally find locally. I've spent ~10 hours troubleshooting and I can't figure it out...

Of note: the test_type view works just fine (just a test view that outputs the subclasses of other models), while the todays_deals does not function. It returns:

```
render_to_string() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

and it's view looks like:
    def view_deals_updated_today(request):
        today = date.today()

```
    todays_deals = Deal.objects \
        .filter(updated_at__gte = today) \
        .exclude(created_at__lte = today) \
        .select_subclasses()

    return render_to_response('test/deal_list.html', context = {'todays_deals':todays_deals})
```

I'm quite confused. Even 'pip freeze' is the same between these environments...

Comment: how about just `{% url 'deals:vendor' vendor_item.slug %}` ?

Comment: What happens if you take the `{% url %}` tag out in line 38? ie just have `<li>{{ vendor_item.slug }} {{ vendor_item.name }}</a></li>`? Does the slug get correctly output along with the name?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

The issue was a single forward slash in the nginx config.

the static portion of the config should be '/static' not '/static/'